# iMacros - Detect {{LOOP}} value number and scrol down the page

Tags: eval, imacros

I found a solution for what I need, but maybe someone can help me optimize it.

When the {{LOOP}} value have 20 to 40,60,80,100,120,140,160, ... 2000... 10000... etc. or more, I need to Scroll Down the page with the value I need.

Because the WebPage is big and I should reach maybe 20000 as the value of {{LOOP}}.
In this case, my solution seems a little out of hand. I would have to repeat the code in many lines.

```
SET !LOOP 20
SET !EXTRACT {{!LOOP}}

SET scrolla EVAL("var x='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var z; if(x=='20'){z=\"javascript:window.scrollBy(0,5000)\";} else{z=\"javascript:window.scrollBy(0,500)\";}; z;")
SET scrolla EVAL("var x='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var z; if(x=='40'){z=\"javascript:window.scrollBy(0,5000)\";} else{z=\"javascript:window.scrollBy(0,500)\";}; z;")
SET scrolla EVAL("var x='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var z; if(x=='60'){z=\"javascript:window.scrollBy(0,5000)\";} else{z=\"javascript:window.scrollBy(0,500)\";}; z;")

'URL GOTO={{scrolla}}
PROMPT {{scrolla}}
```

Someone have another solution for my problem? More optimized? and not using so many lines?
thank you so much

**I am using (FCI):**
iMacros for CR v10.1.1 'PE', CR v105.0.5195.102 (_x64), Win10_x64.
('CR' = 'Chrome' / 'PE' = 'Personal Edition')

**Later edit:**
Another idea that crossed my mind would be to use a .csv and put 20, 40, 50 ... 1000 on the specific line to match the {{LOOP}},  and the other lines 0,0,0,0,. and in EVAL function I will use it (x=='{{!COL1}}') instead of (x=='20'), (x=='40')..

Comment: Ah-ah...!, nice Tries, "magic" Word to search for a (much better) Sol/Implementation is "Modulo"... // To search the iMacros Forum on my Posts, I've already posted that Sol dozens of times... :idea: // Just posted a fairly long Quality Answer to one of your other Qt's, I'll possibly post it as a complete Sol to this one tomorrow...

Comment: @chivracq  your magic word helped me  to have the direction. I will test later on my laptop but I found one of your Sol.  SET reload EVAL("var x; var y=\"{{!LOOP}}\"; if(y%5==0){x='www.google.com';} else{x='';}; x;")
URL GOTO={{reload}}

Comment: Yep indeed, that's "the Principle", but hum, `EVAL("var x; var y=\"{{!LOOP}}\";...` is pretty old Syntax I used to use in 2013/14, while I only started to use the `%` Command/Syntax 1 or 2 years later... (I was using a different Mechanism before...) // I see you've noticed I had edited one of your Qt's, to "simplify" a bit your FCI, or make it a bit "more compact", it is often crucial Info, but it doesn't need to take 1/3rd of the Body of a Qt, => you need x2 Spaces at the end of a Text Line to force a Line Break... (about the 'CR' + 'PE' Acronyms...)